# Android WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, webbrowser, rss

Добрый день!
Изучаю андроид.  Каким образом я могу  сделать так, чтобы после выгрузки rss, каждая новость открывалась не в стандартном браузере, а в приложении? 
Пробовал сделать таким образом:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.txtTitle.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getTitle());

holder.txtPubDate.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getPubDate());

holder.txtContent.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getContent());

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
            if (!isLongClick){
                //Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
                //mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);

                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink())));

            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Далее создал класс, в котором указал layout и WebView**

```
    public class ww extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webo);

    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    webView.loadUrl(data.toString());
    }
    }
```

**И дописал в манифест данную активити:**

```
<activity android:label="TestBrowser" android:name=".ww">
        <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**В итоге после выгрузки новостей, после клика по любой из новости я получаю ошибку:**
*java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.sky.myapplication.Adapter.FeedAdapter cannot be cast to com.example.sky.myapplication.Interface.ItemClickListener
                      at com.example.sky.myapplication.Adapter.FeedAdapter$1.onClick(FeedAdapter.java:86)*

**86 строка:**

```
 mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
 Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink())));
```

**Попробовал реализовать подобным способом:**

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       sharingIntent.setData(Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Open With");
chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Выбираю свое приложение, оно открывает активити и спустя пару секунд все равно открывает стандартный браузер. Что я делаю не так?

Класс для работы с WebView исправил на:

```
    public class ww extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webo);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    webView.loadUrl(data.toString());

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
        this.webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Comment: Свои собственные компоненты лучше открывать явным интентом: `mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
 Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink())), mContext, MyActivity.class);`

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопочка [`править`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/782269/edit). Используйте правку для дополнения/уточнения вопроса вместо комментариев - их не удобно читать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы открыть свою `Activity` лучше и надёжнее использовать явный `Intent` (с указанием конкретного класса) :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity.class);
    // ... добавляем в intent нужные данные
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

`WebView`, по умолчанию отдаёт переходы по ссылкам на странице браузеру. Страница новости скорее всего перенаправляет на другой адрес и `WebView` это принимает за переход по ссылке. Что бы все ссылки открывались в своём же `WebView` достаточно назначить стандартный `WebViewClient`

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!
Только пришлось еще флаг добавить: 
`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`